# How to return array without square brackets or commas

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and I want to return it with the commas and the square brackets removed from the returned value so that I can more easily analyze it and use its contents to make a sentence for a user to read better rather than a confusing script for those who don’t know JavaScript. Is there an efficient way to do this?

```
var a = [5, 6, 7, 3, 1];
console.log(a);

//-> [5, 6, 7, 3, 1] | I want 56731
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "return it with the commas and the square brackets removed"? This doesn't make sense to me. The commas and square brackets are simply the textual notation for an `Array` literal. Also, in your code example you are not returning anything, you are only printing.

Comment: Why can’t you use indexOf on an array? Have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.join()`. This returns a string which is the array's elements joined together with nothing.

```js
var a = [5, 6, 7, 3, 1];
console.log(a.join(""));
```

Comment: Can you break this down more please?

Comment: @sure `.join()` joins the elements of an array and separates each element by the first parameter, which in this case is an empty string, which means there is nothing between the elements. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).